# One exposed filter in separate block for 2 display of one view with Quicktabs

Tags: views, blocks

I have 2 displays for a views (one is clone of other, so the filters are same).

1. One is a block to show with [Quicktabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs).
2. The other is an exposed form with filter on separate block.

The exposed filter works only for 1st display, and if add 2nd exposed form, strange but it works to the 1st display too.

Comment: [Allow multiple instances of the same exposed filter form on a single page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1735096)? [multiple ajax views with exposed filters on one page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113512)

Comment: I dont understand you, i just want one exposed form work with 2 diplsays of view.

Comment: Google 'drupal multiple views one exposed form'

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1547774 i tried this and it doesn't work, maybe is there trouble with Quicktabs?